# Why is the site traffic getting choked once I reach 4 Mb/s Network I/O

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, nginx, varnish

I'm facing this weird issue where I'm unable to tweak the correct value of php-fpm process manager and hence my traffic is getting stuck at a constant `1000 to 1200` concurrent users. (while using a smaller machine I was constantly hitting `2500 to 3000` concurrent users daily).

And I was getting choked at 3000, so I started tweaking and now after hours of racking my brains and monitoring with New Relic, I'm going nowhere. Infact, I've successfully reduced traffic to 1/3rd. Please guide me.

My current php5-fpm conf setting are: /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 300
pm.start_servers = 75
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 150
pm.max_requests = 10000
```

Here's a screensgrab from New Relic
[image]

`php-fpm` takes insane amount of CPU and when it touches near to 100%, traffic chokes and goes down. I'm using `Varnish,` `W3TC` (`object caching` and `DB caching using APC`), `Cloudflare` and even if a few requests can reach php, it shouldn't take so much CPU. Earlier it was not that case before I started tweaking.

Can someone suggest a good setting for my process managers for php-fpm. Please guide me.

Comment: Sounds like this question would fit better over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead of SO (since it is more about server configuration than programming).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the suggestion, I'll post there.